# CLEditor deault text from query

Tags: text, default, cleditor

I have a textarea that displays a text I get from a query. But this textarea runs the  CLEditor plugin and execute the website does show the "CLEditor area" empty. How would you add default text in the plugin? For example:

```
<textarea id="areaEdit" name="areaEdit"><?php echo $row['myText'] ?></textarea>
```

I hope your help, thank you very much.
p.d. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

That is how you would do it. Did you confirm that the data of $row['myText'] actually is valid and has a value? Comment out the CLEditor code and see if it shows up in a basic textarea.